# SignalR server memory consumption (Windsor IHubActivator to blame?)

Tags: c#, signalr, castle-windsor, signalr-hub

I'm testing a SignalR server (self-hosted in a console application) that will eventually form the basis of a data logging system. A test client is making approx 180 calls/sec to the hub, while the messages themselves are very small (just a name/value pair).

I'm using Castle Windsor for DI, with a custom `IHubActivator` to resolve the Hub instance:

```
internal class WindsorHubActivator : IHubActivator
{
    private readonly IWindsorContainer _container;

    public WindsorHubActivator(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public IHub Create(HubDescriptor descriptor)
    {
        var hubType = descriptor.HubType;
        return _container.Resolve(hubType) as IHub;
    }
}
```

Here is the hub class:

```
public class TelemetryHub : Hub
{
    private readonly TelemetryDataService _telemetryDataService;

    public TelemetryHub(TelemetryDataService telemetryDataService)
    {
        _telemetryDataService = telemetryDataService;
    }

    public void LogTelemetryData(string name, double value)
    {
        _telemetryDataService.LogTelemetryData(name, value);
    }
}
```

When the hub class is registered with Windsor as "Transient", the memory consumption climbs steadily until it hits 2Gb then falls over with an OOM exception. If I instead register the Hub as "Singleton" then the application memory consumption remains very low and consistent.

The `TelemetryDataService` class is not the issue. I've commented out the hub's constructor and method code and the problem still occurs.

Out of curiosity I then took things a stage further and changed the `WindsorHubActivator` class to take Windsor out of the equation:

```
internal class WindsorHubActivator : IHubActivator
{
    ...

    public IHub Create(HubDescriptor descriptor)
    {
        return new TelemetryHub(new TelemetryDataService());
    }
}
```

This time the memory problem went away, so I'm assuming Windsor is holding onto the created hub instances and preventing them from being garbage-collected. What's the solution? I understand it's not recommended to use a singleton Hub, and I don't want to leave the `IHubActivator` in the above "hardcoded" state.

Comment: It seems this is a known issue that should be resolved in SignalR v3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For transient components that are explicitly `Resolve`d from the container, [you need to explicitly `Release` them to let Windsor know it can release its reference to them](http://kozmic.net/2010/08/27/must-i-release-everything-when-using-windsor/):

> Tran­sient com­po­nents are sim­i­lar to pooled, because there’s no well known end to tran­sient component’s life­time, and Wind­sor will not know if you still want to use a com­po­nent or not, unless you explic­itly tell it (by call­ing Release). Since tran­sient com­po­nents are by def­i­n­i­tion non-shared Wind­sor will imme­di­ately destroy the com­po­nent when you Release it.

So, I believe you have two options:

1. If you can know where `IHub.Dispose()` will be called, you can just put in a call to `container.Release` there.  This is probably not the best way, since you'd be coupling your usage of `IHub` to how it is created, which is one of the big problems (if not *the* problem) that using an IOC container solves in the first place.
2. If you don't know where `IHub.Dispose()` will be called, you can wrap the hub and container in an object to manage this for you.  Something like this:

   ```
   public class HubContainerWrapper : IHub, IDisposable
   {
       IWindsorContainer container;
       IHub hub;

       public HubContainerWrapper (IWindsorContainer container, IHub hub)
       {
           this.container = container;
           this.hub = hub;
       }

       ~HubContainerWrapper()
       {
           Dispose(false);
       }

       public void Dispose()
       {
           Dispose(true);
           GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
       }

       protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
       {
           if (disposing)
           {
               if (hub != null)
               {
                   try
                   {
                       hub.Dispose();
                   }
                   finally
                   {
                       container.Release(hub);
                       container = null;
                       hub = null;
                   }
               }                   
           }
       }

       // forward all IHub calls to hub member
   }
   ```

   Then in your `IHubActivator`:

   ```
   public IHub Create(HubDescriptor descriptor)
   {
       var hubType = descriptor.HubType;
       var hub = _container.Resolve(hubType) as IHub;
       return new HubContainerWrapper(_container, hub);
   }
   ```

   This way, when SignalR disposes your hub wrapper, it will release the actual hub that you resolved from the container.

Comment: Ingenious! I'll give this a try. I'm assuming this will result in the HubContainerWrapper instances not being released, so there would still be some degree of memory leakage? (Although far less than not releasing the actual hub I guess).

Comment: The `HubContainerWrapper` objects are just regular C# objects, so once whatever hangs on to their reference lets go of them (i.e. whatever stores the returned value of `Create()`), they'll be collected as normal.  I wouldn't expect any memory leakage.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        //this value default is 1000
        GlobalHost.Configuration.DefaultMessageBufferSize = 32;
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```